# How to delete a string from an array of string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a multidimensional array in which I put words inside. After, I ask the user to delete a word. But it won't delete.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    
    int i ; 
    int nbr ;
    char n[50][50];
    char d[50];
    
    printf("Enter the number of word you want : \n");
    scanf("%d",&nbr);
    
    for(i=0; i < nbr ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter words : \n");
        scanf("%s",&n[i]);  
    }
    
    printf("you have enter: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < nbr ; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s \n",n[i]);
    }
    
    
    printf("Which word you want to remove  : ? \n");
    scanf("%s",&d);
    
    for(i=0; i < nbr ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(n[i],d)==0)
        {
            n[i] = n[i+1] ; 
            i-- ; 
        }
    }
    printf("The rest of array is : \n");
    scanf("%s",&n[i]);
    
}
```

> [Error] assignment to expression with array type

Comment: I believe the issue is that you have a two dimensional array and you are trying to treat it like an array of pointers.  You'll have to copy in the actual contents rather than trying to assign a pointer since it is in fact an array.

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to copy strings. Or change it to an array of pointers, and allocate the strings dynamically.

Comment: As a sidenote: ```scanf("%s", &d);``` should be ```scanf("%s", d)```

Answer (score 0):

Although arrays are implemented with pointers in C, the compiler will treat them the differently. As you can see in your own example the line  n[i] = n[i+1] causes the error you see, because n[i] is an array of chars.

Even if you could make the assignment you wanted, the logic of your program still has an error. If you were able to succeed in your call to n[i] = n[i+1] you would effectively be duplicating whatever was in n[i+1] twice.

Instead you likely want to copy n[i+1] into n[i], then copy n[i+2] into n[i+1] and so on. This will be expensive, you may want to look into using a linked list instead, although this really depends on what else you want to do with this data structure.

Comment: Casting to a pointer won't work at all. Arrays are not implemented as pointers.

Comment: You're right, that's my mistake. Declaring n as an array of pointers would be the only way. In which case you would have to dynamically allocate the strings, as you mentioned above. However I did believe C arrays are implemented as pointers, with some amount of niceness from the compiler. If this is not the case could you please point me in the right direction to learn about the actual implementation.

Comment: "*Although arrays are implemented with pointers in C*" no, no, no, arrays are not pointers, nor are they "implemented" using them.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [Error] assignment to expression with array type
> ```

In C an array can not be assigned.

You need to copy the content of the source array are into the destination array.

For the special case of a `0`-terminated `char`array (aka C-string) you can use the `strcpy()` function  to do so:

```
    strcpy(n[i], n[i+1]);
```